# Simple Pop Up on Doc Open

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following, which works great but needs some tweaks and not sure how to go about it.

```
function onOpen() {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var Alert = ui.alert("Arash - $20, Gery - $15, Rachel - $0, Sunny - $0, 
Ling - $15");
}
```

What I am looking for is that in the pop up each Name section ie "Arash - $20" will be on its own row, not running concurrently.

Comment: If you want to put each value for each row, how about modifying to ``var Alert = ui.alert("Arash - $20\nGery - $15\nRachel - $0\nSunny - $0\nLing - $15")``? ``\n`` is used as the line break. Because I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question, I posted it as a comment. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: actually, you understood correctly. and it works now perfectly. thanks so much

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted an answer, because I thought that your question might be useful for other users. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to put each value for each row as follows.

#### From:

```
Arash - $20, Gery - $15, Rachel - $0, Sunny - $0, Ling - $15
```

#### To:

```
Arash - $20
Gery - $15
Rachel - $0
Sunny - $0
Ling - $15
```

#### Modified script:

In order to achieve this, please use `\n` as the line break. So please modify as follows.

From:

```
var Alert = ui.alert("Arash - $20, Gery - $15, Rachel - $0, Sunny - $0, Ling - $15");
```

To:

```
var Alert = ui.alert("Arash - $20\nGery - $15\nRachel - $0\nSunny - $0\nLing - $15");
```

#### Reference:

- [Newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)